# How to split the following list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and trying to understand the concept of lists and for that purpose lets say I have a following list.

```
countries = ['usa uk berlin china africa']
```

How can I split it to get another list where I can access every country separately ? Right now if I do

```
print (countries[0])
```

*it prints **u***

I want something like

```
print (countries[0])
```

must print **usa**

How can I do this ?

Comment: `countries[0].split()` we don't need to provide space as a delimiter, its default.

Comment: `print (countries[0])` will not print `u`. It will if `countries = 'usa uk berlin china africa'`

Comment: Yes please clarify if `countries` is really a list with a string as its first element, or just a plain string (in which case you made a typo and need to remove the brackets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your question is unclear, I'll try to answer for both cases :

1. `countries` is a list of strings
2. `countries` is a plain string

---

If `countries` is defined as you typed it :

That's because you think `countries` is a `list` while it's actually a `list` of `string`, containing only one string!
To get that string into a real list, you might want to use the function [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) :

```
countries = ['usa uk berlin china africa']

# Access first element, the string with the countries, then split it
countries_list = countries_str[0].split()  

print(countries_list[0])
>>> usa
```

Note that in this case `print (countries[0])` would print `usa uk berlin china africa` and not just `u` as you said.

---

If countries is a plain string, just use [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on it.
The only change compared to the first case is that you don't need the `[0]` to access the string.

```
countries = 'usa uk berlin china africa'
countries_list = countries.split()
print (countries_list[0])
>>> usa
```

And in this case you need to remove the brackets in your first code snippet.

Comment: Okay .. my bad, it was a plain string and I was confusing it with list, that second option worked .. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`countries[0]` **doesn't** return "u", it returns the first item in the list, which is the string

```
"usa uk berlin china africa"
```

Having this string, you can `split` it according to space:

```
>>> countries[0].split()
['usa', 'uk', 'berlin', 'china', 'africa']
```

Comment: I tried your code and it still prints **u**

    countries[0].split()

prints **u**

    countries[1].split()
prints **s**

Comment: @0circle no it doesn't

Comment: @0circle They you have a string, not a list of one string.

Comment: Yeah .. sorry, I was confusing it with lists .. I tried your code with another (proper) list and it also worked .. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi there what you have there is a string in a list container hence you need to split it up with the space separator between each countries

```
countries = ['usa uk berlin china africa']
#we now split the countries by the space separator
separated_countries = countries[0].split(' ')
#we can now access each country using the index like so;
print separated_countries[0]
#remember indexing in computing starts from 0 thus the last country can be accessed using the index  totalcountries-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
countries = ['usa uk berlin china africa']
countries = countries[0].split()
for country in countries:
    print country
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce your output.

The way you have written it at the moment, you have a list with one element. Printing the first element would result in:

```
>>> countries = ['usa uk berlin china africa']
>>> print (countries[0])
usa uk berlin china africa
```

I managed to reproduce your output by changing it to `countries = 'usa uk berlin china africa'` (This would print **u**).

**What you are looking for is probably the following**:

```
countries = ['usa', 'uk', 'berlin', 'china', 'africa']
>>> print (countries[0])
usa
```

If your list have to have the format your currently have, you might want to do like Eugene Soldatov suggested:

```
print countries.split(' ')[0]
```

You can read more about lists [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

This was tested with python 3.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Maroun Maroun has you on the right track because your country list is a list of one string.  Split the string, assigning it, `new_list = countries[0].split()` and then the now individual items in the previously continuous string may be accessed via index, e.g., `new_list[2]` as the country of Berlin.